# How to construct a time vector for autocorrelation?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, autocorrelation

I computed the Power Spectral Density of a signal Gxx. Then I selected a range of elements and computed the Inverse Fourier Transform of those elements.

How can I construct a time vector for these elements ?

The sampling frequency Fs = 1652 Hz, the length of Gxx is 8534 and the number of the inverted elements is 210. The autocorrelation in time domain is a sinusoidal free decay signal. I want to evaluate the damped frequency and the damping ratio. of this signal

Comment: Please show (a minimal, reproducible version of) your code, show (a bit of) your data, and try to show where it's going wrong.